# How to deal with ReSharper's name suggestions?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, resharper

Always, I have got the following message:

> name 'byteProivder_LengthChanged' does
>   not match 'Methods, properities and
>   events'. Suggested name is
>   'ByteProviderLengthChanged'

Not even the VS generated method name could get away from this suggestion. For example `FormXXX_Load` is adviced to change to `FormXXXLoad`.

So what should I do? Should I follow the name suggestion or just keep the VS style? 
If I follow the name suggestion, how to configure the ReSharper and let it change the name automatically?
If I do not follow the ReSharper way, how could I turn this name suggestion option off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ReSharper's advice is (in most cases) useful, but sometimes it misses the target and can even be a bit annoying.

You have three solutions for this;

1. Edit the ReSharper's definitions to match your liking (this is possible by selecting "edit X rule settings" from the quick fix menu on the left)
2. Hide the annoying ReSharper message (either locally with a comment or globally by changing the settings for this type of message. Both are possible from the quick fix menu)
3. Ignore ReSharper's message when it's simply useless.

No matter what you choose, make sure your selection encapsulates your entire work (as well as your team's work if you're a part of one). For instance, in the case of option 3, make a list of situations where ReSharper is ignored.

Keeping your code consistent is vital to any project (be it small or large) and should be your first guideline when thinking about ReSharper.

Comment: I disagree.  Names are intended to represent something meaningfull and cannot practically be condensed into (accurate) global guidelines.  For instance, when VS appends _Load, it does so consistently, and thus *recognizably* and *readably* - whether or not that happens to be in any explicit guideline.  Simiarly, any reasonable large project *should* have various readability-enhancing conventions - which, being project-dependant, almost certainly won't fit into a useful global guideline.

Comment: Lest it be forgotten; machine-verification of such naming guidelines comes at a cost.  These warnings distract from real issues in your code and cost time and attention to resolve.  It's a good idea to occasionally improve names to clarify code, but it's a bad idea to *by default* obfuscate code with warnings and squigglies to achieve that.

Comment: @Eamon, a global guide line would always be limited to a given project, so the goal is not to fit all projects into one convention (if this was the case, you'd see many standards regarding the issue). Furthermore, names are intended to represent something meaningfull, as you said, but naming conventions are not about the name, but about the way you present it, so ,again, I don't argue that a global guide line should cover this part.

Comment: @Eamon, regarding your second note, +1

Comment: Yeah, I'm exaggerating a little; indeed :-) I'm certainly not opposed to consistent naming - just resharpers default means of achieving that consistency.

Answer (score 5):

To turn the suggestion off, you can change ReSharper's Inspection Severity.

**ReSharper > Options > Code Inspection > Inspection Severity > Inconsistent Naming**

You can also change or create custom Naming Styles for individual languages.

**ReSharper > Options > C# > Naming Style > Advanced Settings**

More information about creating custom Naming Styles can be found on [JetBrains'](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Coding_Assistance__Naming_Style.html) and on [devloq](http://develoq.net/2011/how-can-i-suppress-inconsistent-naming-inspection-just-for-test-files/).

Answer (score 4):

There is a simple way to disable ReSharper's inconsistent naming evaluation check for an entire file/class.

By adding the following comment to the top of the file/class, ReSharper will not evaluate the naming conventions when analyzing the file/class.

```
// ReSharper disable InconsistentNaming
```

For a code fragment, you can:

```
// ReSharper disable InconsistentNaming
private void btnCreate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
// ReSharper restore InconsistentNaming
{
    //.....
}
```

List of suggested comments provided by ReSharper:

```
// ReSharper disable InconsistentNaming
// ReSharper restore InconsistentNaming

// ReSharper disable CodeCleanup
// ReSharper restore CodeCleanup
```

Comment: Ugh... that's ugly

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I suppress those warnings and then it ignores them.

If you go to ReSharper > then choose Inspection Severity in the Code Inspection menu, you can switch this off.

Comment: This is the best option - the naming guidelines are meaninglessly and annoyingly limiting.  Such guidelines are fine suggestions, but not worth the harassment when you choose to deviate from them (presumably, ironically, for readability reasons).

Answer (score 2):

I do not follow all r# suggestions. The one I don't like I change, the one that can't be changed I turn it off (we have our own guidelines).

Answer (score 2):

You can suppress a single warning instance by adding the following comment before the line with the warning, for example, for the following warning:

> Name 'Counter' does not match rule 'Local Function'. Suggested name is 'counter'.

Disable like this:

```
// ReSharper disable once InconsistentNaming
function Counter() {
    this.pending = 0;
    this.succeeded = 0;
    this.failed = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [StyleCop for ReSharper](https://github.com/StyleCop/StyleCop.ReSharper) and define your own rules or modify default behaviour to follow your style.

Answer (score 0):

ReSharper is trying to make you adhere to Microsoft's own [naming guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx) which is a good idea, especially if your team is not using any naming conventions already. Using a naming convention gives your code greater readability and a more consistent API.

Comment: A naming convention is one thing; an explicit convention is another; and machine-verification of a convention that probably doesn't match your project's reality is again different.

Comment: In my opinion you define your own project's reality.

Comment: My problem with ReSharper isn't naming conventions. I like to follow naming conventions. I edited it a bit and it's very nice. But there are 500 other inspections, which are really-really annoying. And what's even more annoying is that I had to uncheck 500 of checkboxes in Inspection Severity manually, one by one. Because if I don't, I get 500 suggestions per project. And that's if project is small.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to turn off some code inspections, i think, the easiest way is to choice "Inspections options for...." from the menu that shows on the right side in editor (for that particular error/warning).  Then a popup will show up and you can change the behavior of that type of inspections. Last option:"Do not show" does the trick.

This applies to R# 5.0 and probably 4x as well.

In general, you should use the coding standards that you think will fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the screenshot just in case you are having problem looking for ReSharper settings:

Upon clicking Resharper Menu -> Options:

[image: Inconsistent Naming Options]