# Where ReSharper naming rule is defined which prohibits using the prefix "Default" in type names, property names, constant names...?

Tags: c#, resharper, naming, policy

I have the following class with const names and property names starting with Default prefix:

```
public class ComputeInfo
{
    // ReSharper disable InconsistentNaming
    public const string DefaultNetworkName = "default";
    public const int DefaultLinuxDiskSizeGb = 10;
    // ...
    public string DefaultName { get; init; } = string.Empty;
```

or

```
internal class DefaultConsole : IConsole
{
```

All for those names, ReSharper underlines with the "Name ... does not mathch rule ..."

Besides of I would argue why a `DefaultNetworkName = "default"` constant name is not a good idea, this is not the point...

My question is, where is this rule which prohibits the "Default" prefix is defined? The "Edit ... Rule Settings" dialog has no such a part where I can see anything which related this prohibition

Further diagnostics, thx for @mu88 and @Ben comments:

I **cannot** reproduce the behavior in any other solution. I tried:

- using the very same developer machine
- creating a very same application (Console .NET 8) (no issue)
- copying all dotsettings files to the new solution/project (no issue)
- deleting all dotsettings files from the solution/project which exhibits the issue: *the issue still remains there, in all* the 17 projects in the solution
- Visual Studio version: 17.8.0
- Resharper version: 232.0.20231101.132807 built on 2023-11-01

[image]

Comment: I cannot reproduce this :/ are you running the latest version of R#? If yes, can you share your solution?

Comment: Paste the resharper warning message. It should have a number or code which you can look up.

Comment: Many thx. Good points. Editing the OP, see there

Comment: This may be helpful: https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360005140039-Where-is-the-setting-governing-names-of-test-classes-  which I obtained from a search for `resharper "does not match rule 'types and namespaces'"`. Suggests there is something hidden in the options you could tweak.

Comment: This may also help: https://peterdaugaardrasmussen.com/2018/10/18/resharper-how-to-avoid-name-does-not-match-rule-types-and-namespaces/

Comment: Also this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966658/how-to-deal-with-resharpers-name-suggestions